# What grains (and in what ratios) go into a nine-grain flour?

Tags: flour, bread

Many recipes are available for making nine-grain bread, but they presuppose that you have nine-grain flour. We have a wheat grinder so we would like to use it to make our flour to make the bread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no fixed set of grains or ratios that define nine-grain flour. It is just meant to generically suggest "uber-healthy". Some things you may want to use include: whole wheat, rye, triticale, barley, oats, buckwheat, spelt, emmer, millet, flax, etc. Most so-called 9-grains or 12-grain etc will "cheat" and include wheat in multiple forms, like wheat flour, cracked wheat, vital wheat gluten and so forth. In any case, if you are going to use it for bread, you'll probably want at least 50-75% wheat flour so that there is enough gluten to successfully rise. The rest can be in any proportion that pleases you for taste or nutritional purposes.

Answer (score 1):

We ended up buying a nine grain mix from a Mennonite bulk store. It doesn't tell exact ratios, but by law it has to list the ingredients in order of abundance:

- Red wheat
- White wheat
- Rye
- Barley
- Corn
- Millet
- Oats
- Flax
- Buckwheat

Comment: and how was the bread?

Comment: @Doug Excellent. My favorite bread ever.